# Integrate Code Collaborator and Atlassian Stash

Tags: git, bitbucket-server, code-collaborator

Is it possible to use SmartBear Code Collaborator for code reviews with Atlassian Stash?  We've found the tools surround the pull requests to be inadequate for anything beyond a simple code review.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the Product Manager for Stash. First, to answer your question in general, there are plugin points, a REST API and of course git itself as possible means for integrating tools, but I'm not sure of what specifically would be required to integrate in this case.

That said, ideally you'd be able to use Stash to do your reviews and keep everythng, including your workflows, in one place. We are making some improvements to pull requests in Stash, so would love to know more about what you feel is missing. Feel free to comment, or email me: rbarnes --at-- atlassian com

Comment: a bit of an old thread but stash cant be used for reviews in a lot of organizations because it wont allow the comments made to be turned into some kind of jira issue (like crucible does)